# Debugging Apple Watch Wifi

Tags: iphone, wifi, apple-watch, watchos

Apple Watch should connect automatically to any network I was previously connected with on my iPhone.

At my university I need to register devices for network access by providing them with a MAC address. There are **no** further logins required and the network is open.

I connected to this network with my iPhone and it works. Then I registered another device using the MAC address from settings -> General -> About -> MAC Address.

However, the Apple Watch just doesn't connect.

How can this be debugged?

Comment: Can you please add your specs? (which Apple Watch, which version of watchOS/iOS)

Comment: Thank you for the updated question. Have you provided your Apple Watch's MAC address to your university as well?

Comment: You could potentially use a Linux computer with `airodump-ng` to do a packet capture of the raw data flying through the air and see what's happening - is the watch trying to authenticate with the network? Is it getting rejected by the access point? etc..

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately watchOS 3.x can't connect to a Wi-Fi secured by WPA2-Enterprise.

I have experienced the same behavior in the past with watchOS 2.x as well.

This assumes:

- Your university's Wi-Fi is part of eduroam or uses a smiliar Wi-Fi login using your credentials (user name + password)
- Your university's Wi-Fi thus uses the WPA2-Enterprise security protocol
- You can connect to the Wi-Fi just fine with iOS devices like your iPhone
- You use an Apple Watch running watchOS 3.x

With iOS you can enter your credentials. They will get saved and can be transferred to watchOS. The certificate, however, cannot be provided from iOS to watchOS.

## Let Apple Know

Contact Apple and let them know. Apple cares about user's feedback. Use [Apple's feedback form for Apple Watch](https://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html).

---

**Updated answer**

*divB has pointed out that the network uses a MAC address filter instead of the WPA2-Enterprise security protocol*

Please make sure to provide your Apple Watch's MAC address to your university as well as your iPhone's MAC address.

You can find it on your iPhone:

`Watch.app > General > About > Wi-Fi Address`